# Python exclude certain image paths from Beautifulsoup webpage scrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Ive created the following python script to extract image src paths from a specified url:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.example.com/"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

b  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml") 

images = soup.find_all('img')
for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src'):
        print(img['src'])
```

The script works fine but we use a CDN so some image paths are something like:

```
https://i2.wp.com/www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/image-name.png?fit=250%2C250&ssl=1
```

So, i want to be able to exclude certain image src paths (maybe regex) that begin with https://i2.wp.com e.g:

```
url="https://www.example.com/"
exclude=".*https://i2.wp.com"

images = soup.find_all('img')
for img in images:
    if not ** something here to ignore excluded image src urls **:
        if img.has_attr('src'):
            print(img['src'])
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: It's spelled [`.startswith(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith), e.g., `if img['src'].startswith("https://i2.wp.com/"): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex, or just simply use `.startswith()` as stated. Then in your for loop, if it starts with that, `continue`. Which means the code will stop there and go to the next item in your iteration:

```
url="https://www.example.com/"
exclude="https://i2.wp.com"

images = soup.find_all('img')
for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src'):
        if img['src'].startswith(exclude):
            continue
        print(img['src'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
url="https://www.example.com/"
exclude=".*https://i2.wp.com"

images = soup.find_all('img')
for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src') and not img["src"].startswith(exclude):
        print(img['src'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use attribute=value selectors to tie the various requirements (img having src but not having an irc starting with a specific string) into a one liner (no loop):

```
images = [i['src'] for i in soup.select("img[src]:not([src^='https://i2.wp.com/'])")]
```